# Itunes connect device famly, only submit for iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I want my app to only support iphone/ipod. Yet for some reason itunes connect still thinks I'm submitting for Ipad as well. If you noticed below I have my device family set properly to 1 for Iphone/ipod.

Whats up here? Am I missing a setting in xcode?

[image: Xcode]

[image: Itunes Connect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please share your deployment target screen? [image]

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

To set the target devices

```
In the project navigator, select the project and your target to display the project editor.

Click General and, if necessary, click the disclosure triangle next to Deployment Info to reveal the settings.

From the Devices pop-up menu, choose iPhone, iPad, or Universal (to target both families).
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Was exactly what I needed. This was a Noob issue with xcode on my end, never realized you could/should toggle between your project and your targets. "Now you know... and knowing is half the battle..." :)